# Error while upgrading to systemd-219-78.amzn2.0.22

Tags: systemd, package-management, amazon-linux

I have this problem when tryping to upgrade systemd package on AWS instance

```
Error unpacking rpm package systemd-219-78.amzn2.0.22.x86_64
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf: cpio: rename
Verifying    : systemd-219-78.amzn2.0.22.x86_64                                                                                                                                                     1/2
systemd-219-78.amzn2.0.21.x86_64 was supposed to be removed but is not!
Verifying    : systemd-219-78.amzn2.0.21.x86_64                                                                                                                                                     2/2
```

I tried to update the systemd package from 219-78.amzn2.0.21 to 219-78.amzn2.0.22 version.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.

The file `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf` was immutable. I changed it to mutable with `chattr` command.

Comment: Update: 

I check with lsattr command.